# Linker errors when compiling C++ application

Tags: c++, macos, linker-errors

I am attempting to compile a C++ application named "[Nirai](http://github.com/nirai-compiler/src)" on Mac OS X 10.11. This code will compile on Windows, and a few Hackintosh's. I have tried to compile this on 4 other Macs and have received the same error. Here's the full output of the compiler: http://www.pastebin.com/qEEBZ614

I'm using `OpenSSL 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015 darwin64-x86_64-cc`, I installed OpenSSL via homebrew. The version of pycrypto I'm using is `2.6.1`.

Here is the full link command: http://www.pastebin.com/g19UDmjM

The version of clang(g++ calls clang) I'm using is `Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72) x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

If any additional information is needed, I'll provide as much as I can.

Comment: your links are broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! I managed to fix this. Turns out my compiler was picking up some other OpenSSL libs that were not compatible.

After ensuring the correct paths to the new OpenSSL binaries it worked.